# jQuery tabs not working in mobile - custom code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just noticed that on mobile and when resized to mobile my tabs are not clicking and changing and wondering if anyone can see why?

I created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a6k70p0L/2/

Works fine in desktop view, but when resized the click events does seem to fire and change.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var originalTabs = $('.originalTabs').html();

    function clearTabs(){
      $('.originalTabs').html(originalTabs);
    }

    //clearTabs();
    //desktopTabs(); 

    function desktopTabs(){
      clearTabs();

      // cretate tabs for desktop
      var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

      $('#tab_description h6').each(function(i){      
        $(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="tab" id="tab-'+i+'"/>');
      });

      for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ) {
        $('.tabs').append('<li class=""><a href="#tab-'+i+'">'+headers[i].innerHTML+'</a></li>');
      }

      $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
        var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
        var listitem = $(this).find('li');
        active = listitem.first().addClass('active');
        content = $(active.attr('href'));
        $('.tab').hide();
        $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
          $('.tab').hide();
          $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
          content.hide();
          active = $(this);
          content = $($(this).attr('href'));
          active.parent().addClass('active');
          content.show();
          return false;
        });
      });

      headers.remove(); // remove headers from description  
      $('#tab-0').show(); // show the first tab
    }

    function mobileTabs(){
      clearTabs();

      //alert("loaded mobile");

      var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

      $(headers).each(function(i) {
        $(this).append('<a href="#accordion_'+(i+1)+'" id="accordion_'+(i+1)+'"></a>');
        //$(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="aTab" id="tab-'+i+'"/>');
      });

      $('#tab_description h6').first().trigger('click').addClass("active");
      $('#tab_description h6').first().nextUntil("h6").show();
    }

    var tabClick = function() {

        //alert("clicked");
        var accordionContent = $('#tab_description p, #tab_description ul, #tab_description table, #tab_description iframe, #tab_description div');

        $('#tab_description h6').removeClass("active");
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")){
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }

        // Check if current accordion item is open
        var isOpen = $(this).next().is(":visible");

        // Hide all accordion items
        accordionContent.hide();

        // Open accordion item if previously closed
        if (!isOpen) {
          $(this).nextUntil('h6').show();
        }

        // Disabled to stop on mobile auto scrolling down to product description when clicking through...
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 15
        }, 2000);

        return false;
    }

    //bind to resize
    $(window).resize( function() {
      if(isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches){
        desktopTabs();
        $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchstart", tabClick);

      } else if(isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
        mobileTabs(); 
        $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchstart", tabClick);

      } else if(isDesktop) {
        desktopTabs(); 
      }
    });

    //check for the orientation event and bind accordingly
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
      if(isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches){
        desktopTabs();
        $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchstart", tabClick);

      } else if(isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
        mobileTabs(); 
        $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchstart", tabClick);

      } else if(isDesktop) {
        desktopTabs(); 
      }
    }, false);

    if(isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches){
      //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
      desktopTabs();
      $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchstart", tabClick);

    //console.log(originalTabs);
    } else if(isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
      //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
      mobileTabs(); 
      $('#tab_description h6').on("click, touchstart", tabClick);

    } else if(isDesktop) {
      //alert("Desktop");
      desktopTabs(); 
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `$('ul.tabs').each...` in function and call the function when you have done all your appending of a/h6 tags in mobile. Or call your appending functions before the each statement.

The each statement fires and applies to everything that is currently available in the DOM, as your appending function hasn't started yet...the each statement doesn't know it's there. Then your appending stuff happens in your mobile functions and the each statement doesn't know it exists(as it is fired before the mobile functions).

**Edit - Working Answer**

Check the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a6k70p0L/6/

I've mentioned my changes in the comment below.

Comment: I thought that was maybe what i was doing with the desktopTabs() mobileTabs() etc.. im a little confused on what do it here if im honest, could it be possible to get a working solution. I will give it a try now though and see if i an work it out.

Comment: If i'm honest, I think your best solution is to use jquery tabs that are a bit more lightweight. As there is a lot of code there for something as simple as tabs.

Comment: Can only use that certain HTML markup as it pulls from the shopify CMS you see and a lot dependent on it as well so need to get the click events working really plus its due a release today so need to get a fix in measure quickly. Possible to lend a hand on it? would really appreciate it.

Comment: @James check my edited answer... it is now working, i've made modifications to the tabClick function and also the tabClick function wasn't even being called.

Comment: @James No worries, also you may want to grab the code from the latest fiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/a6k70p0L/8/. Basically...where you was using $(this) in the tabClick function it was referring to the window element. I've replaced them all with the variable 'x' and when I call the function 'x' gets substituted with the button element hence `tabClick($(this))` in my each statement.

Comment: Ahh ill check it out, when you click on the fill tab and know this is off subject... any ideas why the video is being hidden?

Comment: Oh its ok i fixed that :)

Comment: @James no worries, i'm off out now. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `append()` with an event like onclick() you should use `delegate()`jQuery function.

Example :

```
$("body").delegate('.class', 'click' ,function()
{
//do something
});
```

It is very helpfull. You can read the cause of this usage in other post on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried using $("body").delegate('#tab_description h6', 'click, touchstart', tabClick); but did not seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/a6k70p0L/3/

Comment: Indeed , the problem is not there. But that you may help one day.